# Query on id field changes argument to NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I encountered an issue today that I have not experienced before. When I try to query any model on the id field it changes my input argument to NULL in the corresponding sql query. The app is running on Rails 7.0.4.

For example running:

```
User.find(123)
  User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = NULL LIMIT 1
```

It's the same if I use `find_by` `find_by_id` or `where`

But if I try to query another column it works as expected

```
User.find_by name: "Edward"
  User Load (4.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" = 'Edward' LIMIT 1
```

I am completely stumped by this, I've walked back in the history to see if there's any recent dependency changes that could have caused this but no luck.

Comment: Do you have anything unusual in the `User` model or database table? Such as a custom primary key.

Comment: And just to be clear: You say it's on **all** models, not just the `User` model?

Comment: What happens if you do `rails new` and try it on a fresh application? I'm wondering if you could help eliminate whether the problem is somewhere in this specific application's code and/or gems, or whether there's something more fundamental going wrong in your database/rails/etc versions.